# Capturing dot and comma in Java RegExp

Tags: java, regex

I have following code in Java:

```
Pattern fieldsPattern = Pattern.compile("(\"([^\"]+)\")|"
                                       +"("+this.field_tag+"([0-9a-zA-Z_]+))");
Matcher fieldsMatcher = fieldsPattern.matcher(field);
while(fieldsMatcher.find())
{
  //...
}
```

This code should capture expressions like "expression" and :expression (field_tag is just ":"). The problem occurs when I try to capture an expression like: "10.1" or "10,1". It dosen't work.

But expressions:

```
"10-1",
"10+1"
```

works as expected.

I also tried use this regexp on regexpal.com - site with javascript implementation of RegExp. On this site expressions like "10.1" and "10,1" works fine.

Is there any difference in java vs javascript in capturing dots? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. Please check your cases again.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
Pattern fieldsPattern = Pattern.compile("(\"[^\"]+\")");
String field =" aa \"10\" \"10.1\" and \"10,1\"";
Matcher fieldsMatcher = fieldsPattern.matcher(field);
while(fieldsMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(fieldsMatcher.group());
}
```

prints

```
"10"
"10.1"
"10,1"
```

The second set of brackets in the regex appear to be redundant, but are harmless.